# photoshop activeDocument

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, photoshop, flash-javascript-api

I am writing a Photoshop plug in in ActionScript 3.

I am having a very confusing and frustrating issue with app.activeDocument.  My code works perfectly with Photoshop for Windows but on a Mac I get the "General Photoshop errooccurreded. This Functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop." error.

To try and get to the root of the issue, I wrote a class just to get the document reference and called it from a test panel.  The class call worked perfectly.  I then included the same class in my main panel project and it breaks.

This is my class: -

```
package DocRefGetter
{
    import com.adobe.csawlib.photoshop.Photoshop;
    import com.adobe.photoshop.*;

    public class DocRefPhotoshop
    {

        public static function getDocRef():Document
        {
            var app:Application = Photoshop.app;

            var thisDoc:Document = app.activeDocument;
            //var thisDoc:Document = app.documents.index(0);  //Tried this method too

            return thisDoc;

        }
    }
}
```

For the purpose of posting here, I have simplified things a little, i.e. I have removed things like the "try, catch" statements but essentially this is the code that does not work in the context of my panel.  I also tried the equivalent call to JSX code with exactly the same result, worked perfectly for Windows, worked in a test panel on Mac, would not work in my main project on Mac.

As I said, inside a test, this works perfectly.  Here is the test mxml code: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" historyManagementEnabled="false">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import DocRefGetter.DocRefPhotoshop;

            import com.adobe.photoshop.Document;

            [Bindable]
            private var hostName:String = HostObject.mainExtension;

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var thisDocRef:Document = DocRefPhotoshop.getDocRef();
                testLabel.text = String(thisDocRef);
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox height="100%" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
        <mx:Button label="Run PS code" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />
        <mx:Label id="testLabel" width="182" text="Label"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

I can't post the main application that it isn't working in as it is extremely large and complicated so what I am asking is has anyone come across a situation before where somehow something is conflicting with this type of document reference?  I have been trying to resolve this for over a week now.  I have tried many different solutions but nothing has worked.  Mac Photoshop just simply doesn't want to see the open document.

Any suggestions are welcome but I am hoping most that someone has come across this exact situation before and has a precise solution.

Many thanks for taking the trouble to take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

> so what I am asking is has anyone come across a situation before where somehow something is conflicting with this type of document reference?

Use one of the following checks:

- Is docref `null`?
- Is the document loaded asynchronously?
- Is the document large enough to warrant a timeout?

**References**

- [Scripting Photoshop: Working with the document model](http://cssdk.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/app_notes/ps_doc_model.htm)
- [Adobe Photoshop CS5 Scripting Guide (pdf)](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs5_scripting_guide.pdf)
- [JavaScript development toolkit | Download Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit CC](http://www.adobe.com/products/extendscript-toolkit.html)

Comment: I wasn't using either Applescript or the command "set docRef to front document".